# Django query related objects

Tags: django, django-models

I have models like this:

```
class A(Model):
    ....

class B(Model):
    a = ForeignKey(A, related_name="bbb")

class C(Model)
    b = ForeignKey(B, related_name="ccc")
    file = FileField( ... , null=True, blank=True)
```

In template or in view I need a mark A row, if some C object related to A has file=None (null) .
Thanks.

Comment: You may want to clarify this a bit. Perhaps add an actual example?

Comment: For example: A - User, B - PhotoAlbum, C - Photo. My query select Users with empty album or with maked object photo, but not uploaded file photo. Just example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, try this:

```
for a in A.objects.all():
    for b in a.bbb.all():
        for c in b.ccc.filter(file__isnull=True):
            a.has_c_with_null_file = True
            a.save()
```

OR

```
    c_without_file = C.objects.filter(file__isnull=True)
    for c in c_without_file:
        c.b.a.has_c_with_null_file = True
        c.b.a.save()
```

OR

```
    A.objects.filter(b__c__file__isnull=True).update(has_c_with_null_file=True)
```

If you leave off the related name, use b_set and c_set.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  A.objects.filter(b__c__file__isnull=True).distinct() is what I need

Comment: Or A.objects.filter(b__c__file__isnull=True, b__c__isnull=True).distinct() !!!! It works